# How to add software installation to GPO in powershell

Tags: powershell, software-distribution, group-policy

Trying the manual steps to create as script:

1. Create GPO
2. Add software installation(msi+mst) for created policy
3. Set link to domain
4. Set computers for this policy

1,2,4 I can do with basic GPO power shell commands (New-GPO, New-GPLink, Set-GPPermission)
But I stuck on second point with adding some msi+mst files to my policy

Hope someone can help me in this situation, because I cant't find any solution for that few days

Answer (score 0):

Well, the information for Software Deployment is actually held in ADSI Edit. I don't think there is a PS Command or CMdlet that would let you add this change.

You could look at ADSI Edit using Powershell. If you do find anything let me know, as I would be interested too.

```
[https://petri.com/active-directory-powershell-with-adsi][1]
```

Comment: I don't think its ADSI. Manually when I edit the software installation its still in "group policy editor": https://i.imgur.com/Pkh1dHH.png